# Atom action performed on save

Tags: gulp, atom-editor

I am using the Atom.io editor. I would like to perform an action while saving file.

Namely I would like to perform bash commend...

Is there a way to do it? Or maybe there is a plug-in which allow to run gulp on save css/js file?

Answer (score 2):

In order to create watcher that will spy on CSS/JS files then perform an action, you can use [gulp-watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-watch). For example:

```
gulp.watch([
    path.join(conf.paths.src, '/sass/**/*.css'),
    path.join(conf.paths.src, '/sass/**/*.scss')
], function(event) {
    if(isOnlyChange(event)) {
        gulp.start('styles-reload');
    } else {
        ...
    }
});
```